# How do I right align a text box over a list?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, less, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a list with a search box on top of it.  I want to right-align the search box so that the right-most edge of the search box aligns with the right-most edge of the list.  Here is a snippet of the html that I am using (along with bootstrap-3).

I created [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5rjXp/) to show what I have now.  This correctly right-aligns the search box, but as you can see, the search box floats on the right of the page. I want it to be above the list, rather than float on top of it.

How do I do this?

Here is the fiddle code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <form class="pull-right" role="form">
                <input class="form-control" placeholder="Filter" />
            </form>
            <ul>
                <li>...items</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use the Bootstrap class **clearfix** in an empty div, after the floating input.

```
<div class="clearfix"></div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DWMtS/